# Jenkins Job DSL issue trying to secure credentials

Tags: java, rest, jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I've been pounding my head with Jenkins trying to get some Job DSL code working. The first part of the code, I have to connect to the bitbucket API and retrieve/filter my bitbucket repos I want to create jobs for. I found this example which works great but the credentials are in in the code.

https://gist.github.com/briscula/fa562f56f825ad1da172696c57c8179c

I tried to wrap the credentials in a 'withCredentials' block like below but I get the error below.

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'bitbucket-app-pass', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
    if (enableAuthentication) {
        String username = USERNAME
        String password = PASSWORD


        // Create authorization header using Base64 encoding
        String userpass = username + ":" + password;
        String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());
 

        // Set authorization header
        connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth)
    }
    }
```

I get this error which I can't seem to figure out how to resolve. If I'm using the wrong plug in or need another plugin or syntax, not sure. Any help is appreciated!

```
ERROR: (script, line 47) No signature of method: utilities.script.usernamePassword() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[credentialsId:bitbucket-app-pass, usernameVariable:USERNAME, ...]]
```